# Animating a Fractal Via OpenGL

Tags: opengl, animation, recursion, callback

I am working on animating a fractal (Triangle fractal) frame-by-frame. I know I need to use a call-back method to do this, but I am not sure how to implement it. I wish to get it working via a left-mouse click so I have this code:

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){
  if(button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN){ 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    divide_triangle(v[0], v[1], v[2], n);
  }
  //Closes the window on right button
  if(button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN){
  exit(0);
  }
}
```

This is my mouse click call back, but this doesn't re-animate the triangle each time the triangle is drawn. How can show the process of the drawing each time I recurse through the triangle drawing?

```
void divide_triangle(point2 a, point2 b, point2 c, int m)
{
  /* triangle subdivision using vertex coordinates */
  point2 v0, v1, v2;
  int j;
  if(m>0){
    for(j=0; j<2; j++) v0[j]=(a[j]+b[j])/2;
    for(j=0; j<2; j++) v1[j]=(a[j]+c[j])/2;
    for(j=0; j<2; j++) v2[j]=(b[j]+c[j])/2;
    divide_triangle(a, v0, v1, m-1);
    divide_triangle(c, v1, v2, m-1);
    divide_triangle(b, v2, v0, m-1);
  }
  else(triangle(a,b,c));
  glutPostRedisplay();
/* draw triangle at end of recursion */
}
```

I want to redisplay once I draw the new triangle here, and make it appear to be an animation, so I guess I would need a delay between the redisplays. How can I set that up? But I also want to make it where I can draw this without animating everytime, I.e. I click a specific mouse key: say 'F1' or some unreserved key and it would just display the final recursive triangle.

[Here is my full code for your viewing](https://gist.github.com/TrivialPants/88969b6b14fa4ff2b5ec):

```
#ifdef __APPLE__ //For use with OS X
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else            //Linux
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

typedef GLfloat point2[2];
/* initial triangle – global variables */
point2 v[]={{-2.0, -1.5}, {2.0, -1.5},
{0.0, 1.5}};
int n; /* number of recursive steps */
int windowX, windowY; //Window size parameters.

float red = .25;
float green = .25; 
float blue = .70;
bool color_state = true;

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y);
void triangle( point2 a, point2 b, point2 c);
void divide_triangle(point2 a, point2 b, point2 c, int m);
void swap_colors();

void display(void){
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  divide_triangle(v[0], v[1], v[2], n);
  glFlush();
}

void init(){
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluOrtho2D(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glClearColor (0.10, 0.10, 0.10 ,1.0);
  glColor3f(red, green, blue);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  if(argc <= 1){
    windowX = 500;
    windowY = 500;
    n = 4;
  }

  else if(argc > 1){
    windowX = atoi(argv[1]);  //atoi converts char to int
    windowY = atoi(argv[2]);
    n = atoi(argv[3]);
  }
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowSize(windowX, windowY);
  glutCreateWindow("N-Force");
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutTimerFunc(30, recurse, -1)
  glutMouseFunc(mouse);
  init();
  glutMainLoop();
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){
  if(button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN){ //Swap colors
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    divide_triangle(v[0], v[1], v[2], n);
  }
  //Closes the window on right button
  if(button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN){
  exit(0);
  }
}

void divide_triangle(point2 a, point2 b, point2 c, int m)
{
  /* triangle subdivision using vertex coordinates */
  point2 v0, v1, v2;
  int j;
  if(m>0){
    for(j=0; j<2; j++) v0[j]=(a[j]+b[j])/2;
    for(j=0; j<2; j++) v1[j]=(a[j]+c[j])/2;
    for(j=0; j<2; j++) v2[j]=(b[j]+c[j])/2;
    divide_triangle(a, v0, v1, m-1);
    divide_triangle(c, v1, v2, m-1);
    divide_triangle(b, v2, v0, m-1);
  }
  else(triangle(a,b,c));
  glutPostRedisplay();
/* draw triangle at end of recursion */
}

void triangle( point2 a, point2 b, point2 c){
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
  glVertex2fv(a);
  glVertex2fv(b);
  glVertex2fv(c);
  glEnd();
}

void swap_colors(){  //maybe add parameters x and y to change colors based on coordinates
  if(color_state == true){
    red = blue = green = .1;
    color_state = false;
  }
  else{
    red = 0.25;
    green = .25;
    blue = 0.70;
    color_state = true;
  }
}


/* TO DO:

   1. add cmd line args, (width, depth, and recursive depth) (CHECK)
   2. add color swap
   3. add exit callback (check> right mouse)
   4. Idle callback for animation
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`glutTimerFunc()` callback](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html) with a Boolean flag to increment the recursion depth value and post redisplays:

```
bool animating = false;
unsigned int n = 4;
void timer( int value )
{
    if( !animating )
        return;

    n++;
    if( n > 6 )
        n = 0;

    glutTimerFunc( 200, timer, 0 );
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        animating = !animating;
        glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
    }
}
```

All together:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

bool animating = false;
unsigned int n = 4;
void timer( int value )
{
    if( !animating )
        return;

    n++;
    if( n > 6 )
        n = 0;

    glutTimerFunc( 200, timer, 0 );
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        animating = !animating;
        glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
    }
}

typedef GLfloat point2[2];
void divide_triangle(point2 a, point2 b, point2 c, int m)
{
    /* triangle subdivision using vertex coordinates */
    if(m>0)
    {
        point2 v0, v1, v2;
        for( int j=0; j<2; j++) v0[j]=(a[j]+b[j])/2;
        for( int j=0; j<2; j++) v1[j]=(a[j]+c[j])/2;
        for( int j=0; j<2; j++) v2[j]=(b[j]+c[j])/2;
        divide_triangle(a, v0, v1, m-1);
        divide_triangle(c, v1, v2, m-1);
        divide_triangle(b, v2, v0, m-1);
    }
    else
    {
        glVertex2fv(a);
        glVertex2fv(b);
        glVertex2fv(c);
    }
}

void display(void)
{
    glClearColor (0.10, 0.10, 0.10 ,1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    float red = .25;
    float green = .25; 
    float blue = .70;
    glColor3f(red, green, blue);

    /* initial triangle – global variables */
    point2 v[]={{-2.0, -1.5}, {2.0, -1.5}, {0.0, 1.5}};
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    divide_triangle(v[0], v[1], v[2], n);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutCreateWindow("N-Force");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to have an idle() callback function, doing PostRedisplay only if your anim flag is on. (idle is called repetitively by glut).